# How can I format-print the date contained in a calendar?

Tags: java, date, calendar

How can I format-print the date returned by this

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
while(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY){
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
}
System.out.println("Next sunday is " + cal.getTime());
```

Basically, I want to print cal.getTime() in this format: yyyy-MM-dd

Note: I am new to Java.

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

....

System.out.println(
    "Next sunday is "
    + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(cal.getTime()))
```

See the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) API docs for reference.

Comment: Do you know why I may be getting these errors:

 [ERROR] [timesheettracking] - Errors in 'file:/C:/Users/me/workspace/tm/src/com/timesheet/tmproject/client/TimeAdd.java'

  [ERROR] [timesheettracking] - Line 73: No source code is available for type java.text.SimpleDateFormat; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Comment: But i inherited the SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 1):

Check [this example](http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/java-example/java-simpledateformat-example.html). All the formatting is done through DateFormat class.

Comment: External links are frowned on, as they can go bad, as this one did.